# Closing parenthesis as delimiter not matched when breaklines=true

Tags: listings, line-breaking, delimiters

I want code in parentheses and in brackets to appear in different colors. In the following document, the words **brackets again** appear in green as intended, and **outside again** is black as intended, but stretches into the margin of the page.

If I uncomment the line `,breaklines=true`, the line is broken between **brackets** and **again**, however, these words and the following are red, i.e. as if a `(`-`)`-delimited section was detected but then the closing `)` was ignored.

What is going on here?

**Addition:** The problem occurs also if there is no line break present, e.g. if I shorten all words in the text to their first letter. The problem goes away in any case if I pick any other kind of delimiter instead of `()`, e.g. `{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{new}{
    moredelim=*[s][\color{red}]{(}{)},
    moredelim=*[s][\color{green}]{[}{]},
  }
\lstset{
  language=new
  %,breaklines=true
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}
outside(in paren) [in brackets (paren+brackets) brackets again] outside again
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have come across a bug arising from the special treatment of the right parenthesis by the line-breaking algorithm of the [`listings`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package. In fact, when the `SelectCharTable` hook used by the `listings` package is executed and line breaking is enabled `)` is defined as a macro, namely by

```
\lst@Def{`)}{\lst@breakProcessOther)}
```

where

```
\lst@Def=macro:
#1->\lccode `\~=#1\lowercase {\def ~}.
```

Unfortunately, this means that `)` is not recognized as a delimiter any more, which eventually leads to your observation.

I’ve put some effort in finding a fix for this bug, but haven’t succeeded so far. (My TeX programming skills are still limited.) So, the only thing I can provide right now is a workaround in the form of a patch that simply cancels the special treatment of `)` by the line-breaking algorithm:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{new}{
  moredelim=*[s][\color{red}]{(}{)},
  moredelim=*[s][\color{green}]{[}{]},
}

\lstset{
  language=new,
  breaklines=true
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{%
  \lst@ifbreaklines\lst@Def{`)}{\lst@breakProcessOther)}\fi
}{%
}{
}{
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
outside (in paren) [in brackets (paren+brackets) brackets again] outside again
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic of that `\lst@Def`. Is there any reason why you use those `\expandafter`'s and not `\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{...}{}{}{}`?

Comment: @egreg: You’re right, `\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}` would be possible as well. I’ve used the alternative formulation since this is the way the control sequence name of the `SelectCharTable` hook is constructed by `\lst@AddToHook`.

Comment: @egreg: `\lst@Def` is completely mysterious to me.

Comment: There's no need to use such a complicated procedure once the control sequence has been built.

Comment: @egreg: You’ve convinced me; I’ve edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A simple workaround would be, instead of using closing parenthesis ')', one can use another character e.g ']' and replace it with closing parenthesis ')'.

```
\begin{lstlisting[literate={(}{{\textbf{(}}}1                          
                           {]}{{\textbf{)}}}1]
(In text I'm closing using]
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: This was the most simple way!
I had `]` in my code so I put `\`)` instead of `)` and did: ```literate={`)}{{\textbf{)}}}{1}```