# How to remove delimiter from morecomment in listings?

Tags: listings

I am using the `listings` package.

According to the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf), this setting will put in the appropriate format the code between `/*+` and `*/` and between `/*-` and `*/`.

```
\lstset{
  morecomment=[s][\color{blue}]{/*+}{*/},
  morecomment=[s][\color{red}]{/*-}{*/}
}
```

The strings `/*+`, `/*-`, `*/` will still appear, which is desirable sometimes.

How can I do remove the delimiters from the rendered code? (I don't want the delimiter strings to be echoed in the listings).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just say `[is]` instead of `[s]`. The `i` stands for invisible.

Comment: @HoodChatham, thanks but from my quick test it looks like `i` makes the whole content disappear.

Comment: I think I found it `\lstset{moredelim=[is][\ttfamily]{|}{|}}`

Comment: Also, I was trying to use close parenthesis in my code which triggered a bug in listings https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74856/1871

Comment: From the comments it seems that you have solved your initial problem but now have a different question. Could you please edit you post so that it is clear what question you are asking and rather than posting snippets can you give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) as this makes it much easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker already seems to have found a solution