# Listing parenthesis highlighting

Tags: listings, highlighting

I'm using the listings package to insert code into the document. My research led me towards the literate option of listings to control operator highlighting. I have one issue - the right round bracket won't accept the rule. Every other line in this snippet of code works as intended.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{verbatim}               % For commenting out multy line commands
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % Dummy Text
\usepackage{listings}               % Code Inclusion

\definecolor{codegray}{HTML}{A0A0A0}
\definecolor{codegreen}{HTML}{00A000}
\definecolor{codeblue}{HTML}{0000A0}
\definecolor{codelightblue}{HTML}{0000FF}
\definecolor{codepurple}{HTML}{F000F0}
\definecolor{codered}{HTML}{FF003A}

%----------------- Code Formatting Options ---------------
\lstset
{ 
backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color;    
commentstyle=\color{codegray},
keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
stringstyle=\color{codelightblue},
identifierstyle=\color{black},
literate=%
*{0}{{{\color{codepurple}{0}}}}1
 {1}{{{\color{codepurple}{1}}}}1
 {2}{{{\color{codepurple}{2}}}}1
 {3}{{{\color{codepurple}{3}}}}1
 {4}{{{\color{codepurple}{4}}}}1
 {5}{{{\color{codepurple}{5}}}}1
 {6}{{{\color{codepurple}{6}}}}1
 {7}{{{\color{codepurple}{7}}}}1
 {8}{{{\color{codepurple}{8}}}}1
 {9}{{{\color{codepurple}{9}}}}1
 {[}{{{\color{codered}{[}}}}1
 {]}{{{\color{codered}{]}}}}1   
 {(}{{{\color{codered}{(}}}}1
 {)}{{{\color{codered}{)}}}}1    %problematic )
 {=}{{{\color{codered}{=}}}}1    
 {+}{{{\color{codered}+}}}1  
 {-}{{{\color{codered}-}}}1
 {*}{{{\color{codered}*}}}1
 {>}{{{\color{codered}>}}}1
 {<}{{{\color{codered}<}}}1
 {|}{{{\color{codered}|}}}1
 {&}{{{\color{codered}&}}}1
 {!}{{{\color{codered}!}}}1
 {:}{{{\color{codered}:}}}1
 {;}{{{\color{codered};}}}1
 {,}{{{\color{codered},}}}1
 {\{}{{{\color{codered}\{}}}1    
 {\}}{{{\color{codered}\}}}}1,
 %tag=[s]{()},
                                 % you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
language=C,                      % the language of the code
basicstyle=\linespread{.9}\ttfamily\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code. Line spread should not be more than 1.
numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
stepnumber=1,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
tabsize=1,                       % sets default tabsize to 1 spaces
breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
numberstyle=\tiny\color{white},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
frame=l,
framesep=4.5mm,                  % sets the thickness of the background
framexleftmargin=0.5mm,          % sets the distance from the code
fillcolor=\color{myDarkGray},          % sets the background colour
rulecolor=\color{myDarkGray},          % sets the left border colour
%aboveskip=5mm,                  % creates space abjove the code, but within the box
%belowskip=10mm                  % creates space below the code, but within the box
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{file.c}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Listings code output with non highlighted right round bracket]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable.

Comment: Your example is *almost* compilable, we just don't have your `file.c`. It would be great if you could add a small dummy file or include it directly with `\begin{listings}...\end{listings}` so we don't have to come up with example code ourselves.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69472/listings-closing-parenthesis-as-delimiter-not-matched-when-linebreaks-true

Comment: I don't understand the patch code suggested in the post that @siracusa suggested as related, but it has solved the problem (as far as I can tell at the moment). How do you upvote a comment?

Comment: On the left beside the comment you find a little upward pointing triangle which is used for upvoting