# Why doesn't \lstset{escapeinside={((}{))}} work as expected?

Tags: formatting, listings, lstlisting

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
\begin{document}

\lstset{escapeinside={((:}{:))}}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
((:\textit{bar}:))
baz
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{escapeinside={((}{))}}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
((\textit{bar}))
baz
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: As far as I understand `escapeinside` it should be defined with two single tokens: `\lstset{escapeinside=()}`. and then `(\textit{bar})`.

Comment: @Red-Cloud I learnt about putting multiple character-tokens for `escapeinside` from these two answers: (1) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181309/18587 (2) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8860/18587

Comment: I see, never used it in this way.

Comment: @Red-Cloud Just went through the documentation: [listings.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf). The documentation seems to be conflicting. In section 5.12, page 40, it says, `escapeinside=<character><character>`. But in section 9, page 56, it shows `\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}` as an example.

Comment: I think this is related to a bug in `listings`, see [Closing parenthesis as delimiter not matched when breaklines=true](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69472/closing-parenthesis-as-delimiter-not-matched-when-breaklines-true). However, the given solution doesn't seem to fix this issue here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package certainly allows for more than one open and close characters in `escapeinside`, for the code changes depending if there is one, two, or more than two characters. In the case of more than one `<character>` as delimiter, `escapeinside` works by making the first token in the `open` and `close` group active characters which look ahead and check if they are followed by the defined characters.

In the first example (let's assume, for simplicity, that you used `escapeinside={(:}{:)}`), `(` is made an active character which looks ahead and checks if it is followed by a `:` character and, if so, starts the escaping. Inside the escaped code, `:` is made active and it looks for a `)` character.

In the second example, `(` is made an active character which looks ahead for another `(`, and starts the escaped code. Inside the escaped code, `)` is made active, and looks ahead for a `)`. However it never finds a `)` *character*, but a `)` *active character*, so it doesn't end the escaped code and just prints a `)` instead. The next `)` does the same and prints another `)`<sup>1</sup>.

This problem does not show in your first example because the character made active and the character looked for are different, so it doesn't show the problem.

Here's a proposal to patch that issue and make `escapeinside` work with whatever character. Beware, though! I didn't test this code extensively (read: I didn't test at all except for the given code) so I don't know if fixing this will break something else. I'd say it won't because it's a very specific bit of code which doesn't seem to be used elsewhere, but the warning is here so you can't blame me afterwards :-)

I modified two definitions, `\lst@CDefIt` and `\lst@IfNextChars@@`, which are used with two token delimiters and three-or-more token delimiters, respectively. I changed the token comparison from `\ifx` to `\if`, which will ignore the catcode difference and will only compare the character itself, so it should do what you're looking for. I marked the two lines I changed. Adding this code to your preamble should do the trick:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\lst@CDefIt#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
        \def#1{#6\def\lst@next{#7#4#8}\lst@next}%
    \else \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
        \def#1##1{%
            #6%
            % \ifx##1#2\def\lst@next{#7#4#8}\else % <--- Before
            \if\noexpand##1\noexpand#2\def\lst@next{#7#4#8}\else % <--- After
                     \def\lst@next{#5##1}\fi
            \lst@next}%
    \else
        \def#1{%
            #6%
            \lst@IfNextCharsArg{#2#3}{#7#4#8}%
                                     {\expandafter#5\lst@eaten}}%
    \fi \fi}
\def\lst@IfNextChars@@#1#2\relax#3{%
    \def\lst@tofind{#2}\lst@lAddTo\lst@eaten{#3}%
    % \ifx#1#3% <--- Before
    \if\noexpand#1\noexpand#3% <--- After
        \ifx\lst@tofind\@empty
            \let\lst@next\@tempa
        \else
            \let\lst@next\lst@IfNextChars@
        \fi
        \expandafter\lst@next
    \else
        \expandafter\@tempb
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you read carefully, you'll notice that the explanation is faulty because it doesn't make sense for the `open` code to work and the `close` code to fail if they do the same thing. Well, it doesn't :) I imagine that the `open` code is very different from the `close` code, thus one works and the other doesn't. To be honest [debugging `listings` on Sunday is painful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445764/134574), so I assumed that part of the code works and didn't try too hard finding out why.

Comment: If only debugging `listings` were not painful during the week ... ;)